# Using Angular's $interval service without triggering digest

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a timer in a template, which updates every second using angular's $interval service.

```
        var now = moment();
        var startActual = moment(scope.vm.start_actual);
        var duration = now.diff(startActual);
        timer = $interval(function(){
          duration = moment.duration(duration + 1000, 'milliseconds');
          var d = Math.abs(duration.days());
          var h = Math.abs(duration.hours());
          var m = Math.abs(duration.minutes());
          var s = Math.abs(duration.seconds());
          scope.mins = prefix + (d <= 9 ? "0"+d : d) + ':' + (h <= 9 ? "0"+h : h) + ':' + (m <= 9 ? "0"+m : m) + ':' + (s <= 9 ? "0"+s : s);
        }, 1000);
```

I then have {{mins}} in my view. This works correctly, but I just realised this is triggering a digest cycle every time this function runs (every second). This app is very complex and this seems like a massive unnecessary cpu load, when all I'm updating is a timer. I've noticed the $interval function as an optional invokeApply param, but when I set this to false, the timer doesn't render to my template at all. How can I set up this timer so it updates every second, but doesn't trigger a full digest cycle? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a very small bit like this I'd suggest using small directive that would update the element directly without causing `$digest` cycle every second (it can be really troublesome when you have bigger app.

I've quickly wrote a directive like that

http://plnkr.co/edit/oA0C6ou29hlKZYVhkRNv?p=preview

```
app.directive('procrastination', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var time;
      time = 0;
      setInterval(function() {
        time++;
        element.text("You have wasted " + time + "s");
      }, 1000);
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 5):

`$interval` has an extra [fourth argument](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) that can be used for this:

```
timer = $interval(function(){
  // Your code here
}, 1000, 0, false);
```

In this example:

- 1000 is your interval
- 0 is the number of repetitions (0 for unlimited)
- false means not to perform dirty checking (do not use 'apply' to do changes)

Now, if you need other watchers to realize that you have updated the `mins` variable, you definitely need to trigger a digest cycle.

Since you want to avoid this, imho, optimal performance can be achieved only by setting `invokeApply` to `false` and directly manipulating the DOM in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough & quick answer but I already mentioned I've tried the invokeApply param & it didn't help

Comment: Indeed, I later realized, hence my comment that you would need to update DOM manually. Depending on your case, this can be done with a directive, a directive + service, or directly updating DOM from your Interval function. Anyhow, others have posted better answers. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Angular only does updates during a digest, so if you set the `invokeApply` parameter of `$interval` to `false` your view won't be updated automatically, as you've already noticed.

However, the digest may not be as CPU intensive as you think. The way Angular's digest works is that it walks over all scopes and checks the registered watches (internal angular features like template interpolation also add watches) comparing current value to previous value. Only if a watched expression has changed does it do an update. If the only thing that has changed is one variable the digest may only take a few milliseconds, even for complex apps. You can time it for yourself.

```
var start = +new Date();
$rootScope.$digest();
console.log(+new Date() - start);
```

If it is too slow you can trigger a digest for only a specific scope and it's children. In your case

```
timer = $interval(function() {
    ...
    scope.$digest();
}, 1000, 0, false);
```

Which will only do a digest for `scope` and any child scopes, rather than a full digest. This will be quicker if your most CPU intensive watches are not within this scope.

Keeps in mind that this only works with `scope.$digest`. `scope.$apply` triggers a full digest (from `$rootScope`).